# Regex solution for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, cocoa-touch

What is the best method for using **Regular Expressions** within Objective-C?

There seems to be some open source project that provide **regex** support, can any one recommend one?

Also I looked at `NSPredicate`, can anyone suggest any **regex** examples?

Background: I want use regex mainly for validation, IP's, email addresses, internal ID's etc

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422138/regular-expressions-in-an-objective-c-cocoa-application. `NSPredicate` examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458881/nspredicate-and-regex, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582700/nspredicate-and-simple-regular-expression-problem. If you're concerned mostly with targeting the iPhone OS, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444772/best-regex-library-for-iphone-sdk-app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read the [full post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/verifying-that-string-is-email-address.html) over at http://cocoawithlove.com.

> In Cocoa, NSPredicate works in much
>   the same way as the "WHERE" clause of
>   SQL. The main reason that NSPredicate
>   is being brought to the iPhone is that
>   NSPredicate fulfils the same role in
>   Core Data that "WHERE" clauses fulfil
>   in SQL — to allow the persistent store
>   to fetch objects that satisfy specific
>   criteria.

```
// given an NSDictionary created used the above method named "row"...
NSPredicate *johnSmithPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname = 'John' AND lastname = 'Smith'"];
BOOL rowMatchesPredicate = [johnSmithPredicate evaluateWithObject:row];
```

**Verifying an email address**

> The "LIKE" comparison operator in
>   NSPredicate
>   (NSLikePredicateOperatorType) is
>   commonly used as a convenient means of
>   testing if an NSString matches a
>   Regular Expression. It's advantage
>   over full libraries with greater
>   options and replacement capability is
>   that it is already in Cocoa — no
>   libraries, no linkage, no hassle.

You can do a simple test:

```
NSPredicate *regExPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regularExpressionString];
BOOL myStringMatchesRegEx = [regExPredicate evaluateWithObject:myString];
```

> The only question that remains is:
>   what is a regular expression that can
>   be used to verify that an NSString
>   contains a syntactically valid email
>   address?

```
NSString *emailRegEx =
    @"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"
    @"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
    @"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
    @"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
    @"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
    @"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
    @"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
```

Comment: I noticed that this monster regex works on the iPad simulator, but not on the iPad hardware (as of version iOS 4.2).

Answer (score 13):

```
NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '.*@.*\..*'"];
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:@"mail@domain.com"];
```

According to the [Predicate guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868):

> **Matches**
>   The left hand expression equals the right hand expression using
>   a regex-style comparison according to
>   ICU v3 (for more details see the ICU
>   User Guide for [Regular Expressions](http://icu.sourceforge.net/userguide/regexp.html)).

There's even an [example written by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794) that can be found in the guide.

Instead of `SELF` you could also use a [key path](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/). (And possibly [some other literals](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215930) too.)

Answer (score 5):

- Desktop: [RegExKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/#Latest) like [Mr. Vile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845317/regex-solution-for-objective-c/845325#845325) mentioned.
- iPhone: [RegExKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/#RegexKitLite) works great.

Answer (score 5):

Try the official NSRegualExpression that's available since iOS 4.0:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: +1 Official regex solution. It would be nice if you could provide an example too.

Answer (score 2):

Have a try with CSRegex: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CSRegex

It is meant to be a quick and simple regex class that can be dropped into any Cocoa project with a minimum of fuss. It consists of only two files, and no external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

try this: http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I haven't tried it but this seems to be exactly the right thing. (Note the requirement to include a copyright notice in distributed programs using the framework.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the libregex wrapper in the Google Toolbox for Mac:
http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMRegex.h