# NSPredicate and simple Regular Expression problem

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, nspredicate

I'm having problems with simple NSPredicates and regular expressions:

```
NSString *mystring = @"file://questions/123456789/desc-text-here";
NSString *regex = @"file://questions+";

NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
BOOL isMatch = [regextest evaluateWithObject:mystring];
```

In the above example `isMatch` is is always false/NO.

What am I missing? I can't seem to find a regular expression that will match `file://questions`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSPredicates seem to try and match the entire string, not just a substring.  Your trailing `+` simply means to match one or more 's' characters.  You need to allow a match for any trailing characters.  This works: `regex = @"file://questions.*"`

Answer (score 5):

If you're just trying to test whether the string exists: try this

```
NSString *myString = @"file://questions/123456789/desc-text-here";
NSString *searchString = @"file://questions";

NSRange resultRange = [myString rangeWithString:searchString];
BOOL result = resultRange.location != NSNotFound;
```

**Alteratively**, using predicates

```
NSString *myString = @"file://questions/123456789/desc-text-here";
NSString *searchString = @"file://questions";

NSPredicate *testPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH %@", searchString];

BOOL result = [testPredicate evaluateWithObject:myString];
```

I believe that the documentation states that using a predicate is the way to go when just checking to see if a substring exists.

Comment: Or `hasPrefix:` for the begins-with case. And there are predicate operators for both of these (and ends-with), which one may prefer if they do not need a regular expression. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html