# Wildcards in strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm interested in using rangeOfString with some wildcard characters as part of a search string.

For example, if I have several strings like "244px" and "356px" and I want to convert all such strings to "320px".  Is there a way I can use wildcards to get the desired result?

Comment: You can `#import <regex.h>` and use that (`man 3 regex`) but I wonder if there's some more "cocoa-like" way to do this.

Comment: I was about to post an answer regarding `NSPredicate` but then I noticed the `iphone` tag. As far as I am aware, predicates are only available on Mac OS.

Answer (score 6):

If you could use regex, you can do substitution for this pattern `"[1-9][0-9]+px"` to `"320px"`

Comment: Oh, yes, correct. It was intentional, May be I shouln't limit that, So, To match any digits, please use `"[0-9]+px"` Don Wilson.

Comment: Can I use regex in an Objective C string like that?

Comment: Yes. Please take a look this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845317/regex-solution-for-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

[RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) is what you want, it has a small NSString extenstion class that lets you use the built-in regex libraries easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSNumberFormatter configured to the right pattern.