# NSPredicate and Regex

Tags: objective-c, regex, nspredicate

Can someone please help me with using Regex with NSPredicate?

```
NSString *regex = @"(?:[A-Za-z0-9])";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
if ([pred evaluateWithObject:mystring])
{
  //do something
}
```

testing the above wth mystring - qstring123 doesn't seem to work. I am expecting it to enter the if condition because it supposedly should match the regex.

Besides, I need a regex for alpha numberic allowing commas and spaces.

will this work?

```
@"(?:[A-Za-z0-9])*(?:,[A-sa-z0-9)*(?:\s[A-sa-s0-9])"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my experimentation, it tries to match the regex against the entire string, and won't match inside a string.

Therefore, the regex `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` works, but `[a-zA-Z0-9]` does not.

With that in mind, you may want to rework your comma-matching predicate, or use a more full-featured regex solution, like the amazingly awesome [RegexKit and RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net).

Comment: duh' i missed the + in the end. I actually used * and it worked. Whats the difference?

Comment: `*` matches 0 or more times, `+` matches 1 or more times.