# Word boundaries (\b) in NSPredicate causing NSFetchRequest to return no managed objects

Tags: iphone, regex, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

Using Core Data w/a sqlite store on iPhone.... I've got a bunch of comic book image entities, each with a string that includes the comic's issue#, e.g.: `image.imageTitle = @"Issue 12: Special Edition";`

Part of the UI allows the user to type in an issue number to jump to the next issue. My initial code for this was sloooooooow because `imageAtIndex:` queries Core Data for one object at a time. Over several hundred issues, it could take upwards of 40 seconds just to get through the first loop!

*Slow Code:*

```
 // Seek forward from the next page to the right
 for (i = currentPage + 1; i < [self numberOfPages]; i++) {
  iterationString = [[self imageAtIndex:i] imageTitle];
  iterationNumber = [[iterationString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonDigits] intValue];

  if (issueNumber == iterationNumber) {
   keepLooking = NO;
   break;
  }
 }
 // If nothing was found to the right, seek forward from 0 to the current page
 if (i == [self numberOfPages] && keepLooking) {
  for (i = 0 ; i < currentPage; i++) {
   iterationString = [[self imageAtIndex:i] imageTitle];
   iterationNumber = [[iterationString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonDigits] intValue];

   if (issueNumber == iterationNumber) {
    keepLooking = NO;
    break;
   }
  }
 }
```

Hoping for a much more efficient solution, I decided to try making a direct query on Core Data like so:

```
    NSString *issueNumber = @"12";
    NSString *issueWithWordBoundaries = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b%@\\b",issueNumber];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(groupID == %@) AND (imageTitle CONTAINS %@)", groupID, issueWithWordBoundaries];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CBImage" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

 [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
 [fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:NO]; // Not sure if this is needed, but just in case....

 // Execute the fetch
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    // [fetchedImages count] == 0
```

Between the [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) and the [ICU regex specs](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), I figured the \b's would help prevent a search for 12 returning 120, 121, 122, etc. Instead, it doesn't return anything from the store at all!

On the other hand, if I leave off the word boundaries and search instead for `stringWithFormat:@"%@",issueNumber`, I get dozens of managed objects returned, from 12 to 129 to 412.

My best guess at this point is that I've run into one of Core Data's [Constraints and Limitations](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001792-249799). If not, what am I doing wrong? If so, is there a workaround that offers both an exact match *and* the speed of a single fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the word boundaries were a red herring: My problem was a variant on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458881/nspredicate-and-regex): The regex couldn't succeed without some wild cards to match the bits I didn't care about in the imageTitles.

The general case solution to finding an exact phrase using NSPredicate is therefore:

```
NSString *exactPhrase = @"phrase_you_hope_to_find_in_another_string";
NSString *regularExpression = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*\\b%@\\b.*",exactPhrase];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stringToSearch CONTAINS %@", exactPhrase];
// Assuming a string or an entity's string attribute named stringToSearch
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like you aren't actually using `regularExpression`, instead doing a CONTAINS search using your original search phrase.

Comment: Huh, it sure looks like it, @taber. To tell the truth, it's been long enough that I have no memory of the project, or what the problem was. This question has had very little activity in 4 years, so I think I'll just flag it for deletion. :-)

Comment: I'd leave it up, I actually found it while looking to use a predicate match w/ word boundaries and it helped me!! You just have to do: `"stringToSearch CONTAINS %@", regularExpression` but I also ended up having to escape special chars in `exactPhrase` first.

Comment: OK. Leaving it up, then. Apologies to anyone who gets this far and _doesn't_ find what they need. ;)

Comment: Cool, sorry what I wrote should have been `"stringToSearch MATCHES %@", regularExpression`

Answer (score 3):

`\b` refers to a backspace character. Try

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b%@\\b",issueNumber];
//                           ^^   ^^
```

And to perform RegEx match, use MATCHES, not CONTAINS.

Comment: Great catch, but unfortunately that was just a typo on my part caused by having tried so many variants on the expression. Escaping the \'s still gives the same results: nada!

I've updated my question from @"\b%@\b" to @"\\b%@\\b" now, though. Thanks, Kenny!