# NSPredicate with core data, search word with boundaries in string attribute

Tags: ios, regex, core-data, nspredicate

I feel like the answer to my question might already be somewhere on this forum, but after hours of scouring I just can't quite seem to get it right. I've never used SQL before so please bear with me.

I have a core data model with only one entity and that entity has an attribute called "definitions" (each entity in the database is a dictionary entry). What I want to do is search the definitions for an input string with *word boundaries*. If I do a simple `CONTAINS[cd]` search with NSPredicate and the input text I get what I'm looking for, except that I also get definitions that contain the input sequence of characters, regardless of boundaries.

So I've also tried building a regex string like `@"(?w).*\\btheWord\\b.*"`, along with the `MATCHES[cd]` search command, but I read on other posts that can only be used when searching NSStrings, and regardless it didn't work.

This should be simple but I'm stumped. Any help appreciated.

EDIT : Here's an example of what I'm doing

```
YTAppDelegate * delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext * context = delegate.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest * request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"YTDictData"];


NSString * searchTerm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'(?w).*\\b%@\\b.*'",[NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:inputText]];

NSString * searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"definitions contains[cd] %@",searchTerm];

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:searchString];

NSError * searchError = nil;

NSArray * searchResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&searchError];
```

In this case, if I were to search for the word "hello", I would get no matches.

However if I do not format the `searchString` string for regex searching (ie `searchString = inputString`), I will get any definition that contains the sequence of characters "hello". I need to be able to find strings which contain the string "hello", but I also need the added constraint that I want "hello" to be recognized as a word with boundaries.

Comment: Show your original attempt and explain what it returns (that is right and wrong).

Comment: Hi @Wain thanks for your suggestion. Please take a look at the edits.

Comment: Have you tried using `MATCHES` for the regex match? See Apple's "Predicate Programming Guide".

Comment: @TomHarrington yes I have. The `MATCHES` search also returns no results. Is special formatting required for a `MATCHES` command? Can you use `MATCHES` when searching a core data database? From my understanding the regex searching only works when searching NSStrings that are already in memory. I would prefer to take advantage of the SQL interfacing that core data has built into it.

Comment: According to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2885731/2128900 it's possible to use regex in a fetch request's predicate. Maybe the syntax which you use doesn't work with SQLite store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said in the comments, you have to use the "MATCHES" operator
for regular expression matching. In addition, you should not use
`stringWithFormat` to build the predicate string (your `searchString` 
variable).

This is how it should work:

```
NSString *searchTerm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*\\b%@\\b.*",
            [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:inputText]];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"definitions MATCHES[cd] %@",
                                    searchTerm];
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the nuance about using another string directly in the `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]` method - beforehand I had to insert `'` marks, otherwise I would get a SQL error. However those `'` marks were probably being incorporated into the search parameter, which is why I wasn't finding anything.

Comment: @Matt: You are welcome. – The main problem in your method is actually the "backslash-b". In `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:searchString]` this becomes a backspace character.