# NSPredicate match string by words

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsstring, nspredicate

I have an array of strings as below:

```
["Milk","Milkshake","Milk Shake","MilkCream","Milk-Cream"]
```

and if I search for "milk" then results should be `["Milk","Milk Shake","Milk-Cream"]` i.e. search by words.

With the predicate as

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tagName CONTAINS[c] %@",containSearchTerm];
```

I am getting all the results from above array. How can I perform match using words ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Predicate in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176605/using-predicate-in-swift)

Comment: @dahiya_boy: it's completely different.  have you read my question ?

Comment: "Milkshake" does contain "milk" so your expected result is wrong.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28116698/1187415 – that's in Objective-C, but shows the idea, and should be easy to translate to Swift.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: consider it case-insensitive

Comment: Yes of course, otherwise your expected result should have been empty. As mentioned in the linked question you need to use MATCHES and regular expressions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a “regular expression search” in order to match against word boundaries, that is done with "MATCHES" in a predicate. Here is an example (essentially translated from [NSPredicate with core data, search word with boundaries in string attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104948/nspredicate-with-core-data-search-word-with-boundaries-in-string-attribute/28116698#28116698) to Swift):

```
let searchTerm = "milk"
let pattern = ".*\\b\(NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: searchTerm))\\b.*"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "tagName MATCHES[c] %@", pattern)
```

This searches for all entries where the `tagName` contains the given search term, surrounded by a “word boundary” (the `\b` pattern).

Comment: you saved the day!