# NSPredicate and NSRegularExpression

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, ipad, core-data

That should be really simple but it doesn't want to work. I want to fetch CoreData using a NSPredicate that uses a NSRegularExpression. I would like to search for myString or myString_10 (10 being any possible number, eg. myString_333).

This is my code:

```
NSString *regexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_[0-9]+", value];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionSearch                                  
                                                                             error:&error];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(label = %@) OR (label = %@)", value, regex];
```

value is a string and label is the entity's key.

If value is "New Project", the NSFetchRequest returns an array with one object, although, I have two labels in my model ("New Project" and "New Project_1") that should be fetched.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression needs to be an NSString or part of the predicate when used. See [Regular Expressions in the Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html).  Try using MATCHES instead of = and `regexString` instead of `regex`. You can reference [ICU Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) for patterns if you have any issues.

Comment: I read it. I didn't find the part where it says that the regular expression needs to be part of the predicate string. See that example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458881/nspredicate-and-regex

Comment: I will edit and re word it. The problem I was trying to point out is that you are using an `NSRegularExpression` and not an `NSString`. You can still use %@ but with a string.