# Fetch data with complex criteria

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

My app has relatively simple model (inherited from existing web-site's model).

One of the attributes of the model is `date`. Unfortunately, values for this attribute are quite free-form and of type `String`. I mean, values are like:

- "June 1888, Arles"
- "c. 1530"
- "1634-37"
- "1508"

Is there a way to build a predicate that will allow me to transform these values to integer values so that I can perform search on values of the `date` attribute?

Currently I am using simple approach:

```
NSString *format = @"date contains[cd] %i";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format, year];
```

but it's not allowing me to find everything between two given dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You... may have a problem here. Any date can be transformed to an integer value, and `NSDateFormatter` does a decent job of parsing dates *if you know what format to use*. You seem to have multiple, very different formats, so you're not going to get away with a simple transformation or search to get integer values for your date strings.

Finding just a four-digit year would be pretty easy, but your example of "1634-37" kind of blows that idea away. If your search was for 1636, it should match, but it won't without some extra help. If you can accept a certain margin of error, you might not care-- just call that one 1634 and be done with it. If not, first you'll need a range of dates (min 1634, max 1637) rather than a single date, and second, you'll need some way to realize that the "-37" should be applied to the "16". Good luck with that, because this is rapidly becoming a complex problem.

**If there are only a few possible date formats**, you could come up with a parser for each one and then either use regex matching or trial and error to choose the parser for a string. If there are **lots** of formats though, you're kind of screwed. You'll be better off editing the data by hand, entering the date in a preferred format that your app can make sense of. Ultimately this really depends on how exactly you need to use the data and on how much error you can tolerate in the results.

On a slightly separate note, if it were me, I'd want to convert these to numeric values when I received the data from the web server. Then when doing a fetch, I'd be able to use numeric matching in the predicate for speedy results. Matching strings-- especially if you need to use a regular expression-- is very slow compared to numeric comparisons.

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right and it would be better to convert values beforehand. After all, data is rarely changed and I can tolerate some inaccuracies like treating 1634-37 to be 1634.

Answer (score 1):

Combine NSPredicate with regular expressions. Here is a link. Use regex to search for a 4 digit number
[NSPredicate and Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458881/nspredicate-and-regex)

Comment: Thank you. It's great there is a possibility but I would better stay away from regexes :-) Anyway, thank you again.