# Filtering NSMutableArray with NSPredicate and regex

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a `NSMutableArray` containing `NSString`.
I need to filter only the objects that begins with `(^WS|WV)[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}`
How can I do it with `NSPredicate`?

Assuming that the array is called myArray, how can I write it?

Answer (score 0):

Just google it to see a lot of answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458881/nspredicate-and-regex):

```
NSArray *array = @[@"WSPS01", @"WLP05", @"1112"];
NSString *regex = @"(^WS|WV)[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred]; 
// filteredArray contains only WSPS01
```

`array` - its your `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. I need to obtain only the array that begins with WS or WC or WV than 2 digits and than 2 numbers. but this code returns nil .

Comment: @yorh don't know, what you do, updated code with full example, copy paste it to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and see the result - it works

Comment: the problem is that the string only begins with for example WSPS01 and then continues with other letters and numbers like: WSPS01 11223345674 LMMc ff 567 etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

this is the correct regex:

```
NSString *regex = @"(^WS|WV|WC)[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}.*"
```

The only question that I still have is why the MATCHES operator works and the BEGINSWITH not...