# Parsing strings: String before character

Tags: ios, swift

Input:

```
chris@mydomain.com
steve@mydomain.com
```

Output:

```
chris
steve
```

I'm looking to get the substring before the `@` character. In Python, I would use something like: `myString = myString[:myString.find("@")]` but I think Swift's version is very complex, at least from what I've been reading. Would it be better to bridge to Obj-C in this case, since Swift's indexOf/find function looks something like this mess: [Finding index of character in Swift String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029163/finding-index-of-character-in-swift-string) ?

Something like this, even though it's using arrays, seems to be the simpliest route:

```
contact = contact.componentsSeparatedByString("@")[0]
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, Python `myString[:myString.find("@")]` is equivalent to:

```
myString[myString.startIndex ..< find(myString, "@")!]
```

But this causes a runtime error unless `myString` contains `"@"`.

This is safer.

```
if let found = find(myString, "@") {
    myString = myString[myString.startIndex ..< found]
}
```

Note that, `find()` searches `Character` only, not substring. so you cannot:

```
find(myString, "@mydomain")
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
let arr = split(contact, { $0 == "@"}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)
println(arr[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have hit the nail on the head.  Another option is to use regular expressions to find it.  I'm still learning swift, but the objective-c version of things is as follows:

```
-(NSString*) parseEmailPrefix(NSString*)email{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *pattern = @"([A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+)@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                            options:0
                                                                              error:&error];
    NSTextCheckingResult *result = [expression firstMatchInString:email 
                                                      options:0
                                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, email.length)];
    return [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]];
}
```

This is in my opinion harder to read, but it has the added benefit of validating the email as you go.

Regex credit: [Regex for email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760787/regex-for-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

And then there is this Obj-C snippet, which addresses more specifically the data given in the question. (Forgive that I have not translated to Swift, still working on that skill.)

```
NSString* email = @"chuck@norris.net";
NSURL* theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto://%@", email]];
NSLog(@"%@ at %@", theURL.user, theURL.host);  // yields "chuck at norris.net"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var str: String = "Hello@World"
let a = str.componentsSeparatedByString("@")
println("\(a[0])")
```

Output is "Hello"