# how to search for whole words efficiently in a sqlite db

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

I have a table that has a title  column.  I want to search for whole words like foo.  so  match  " hi foo bye" o "foo", but not  "foobar" or "hellofoo".  Is there a way without changing the table structure to do this? I currently use 3 like queries, but it is too slow, I have " select * from articles where title like '% foo' or title like 'foo %' or title = 'foo' or  title like '% foo %';
There has got to be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in a search indexer like lucene, ferret, or sphinx.  These would run as separate processes that would index your data for fast searching where stemming, etc. can be configured.

Alternatively, depending on your data, you could just return all results that contain "foo" in any context and then filter them with regular expressions or such outside of the database.  This might be an improvement depending on the characteristics of your data.

Answer (score 0):

spontaneous answer:

use the regexp **operator** instead of the **like** operator.

**EDIT** I just realised that regexp is not always included with SQLite. You might have to compile you own ... in other words, it's not there by default ..

**EDIT2**

here's a working Perl sample ..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;

# connect to the DB
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=dbfile","","");

# create ugly, pureperl function 'regexp'
# stolen from http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tokuhirom/20090416/1239849298
$dbh->func(   "regexp"
            , 2
            , sub { my ( $pattern, $target ) = @_;
                         utf8::decode($pattern);
                         utf8::decode($target);
                         $target =~ m{$pattern} ? 1 : 0;
              }
            , "create_function" );
# drop table, if it exists
$dbh->do('drop table if exists foobar');
$dbh->do('create table foobar (foo varchar not null)');
my $sth=$dbh->prepare('insert into foobar (foo) values (?)');
while (<DATA>) { chop;$sth->execute($_); }
#query using regexp
my $a= $dbh->selectall_arrayref( 'select foo '
                                .'from foobar '
                                .'where foo regexp "^foo$|^foo\s+.*|.*\W+foo\W+.*|.*\W+foo$"'
                               );
print join("\n", map {$_->[0];} @{$a})
__DATA__
foo
foo
barfoo
foobarfolo
sdasdssds bar dasdsdsad
dasdsdasdsadsads foo! dasdasdasdsa
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I am on the iphone, I can add these regexes to the iphone?

Comment: I would assume you could. But but **not using Perl**. There must be a way to add the function "regexp" using objectve c.

Answer (score 0):

There are various regexp libraries that you can include in your iPhone application by linking to them in your build.

See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444772/best-regex-library-for-iphone-sdk-app) for further info.