# How to Extract a Numerical Value from a String?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, phone-number

Is it possible to extract a number from a string. For example, I have a string:

```
my name is shishir and my number is 98890876478
```

Can I extract on `98890876478` from the above string?

Or if my string is:

```
my name is shishir and my number is XXX98890876478XXX
```

In this condition can I extract `98890876478", which is in between of XXX.

Is it possible to do this?

I am getting a message from a server which should be in the format as above, and I need the numeric value for further operations

### Edit:

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
NSString *logString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theXML]; 
NSString *digits = [logString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]; 
NSLog(@"Message id: %i", [digits intValue]);
```

which outputs:

```
2010-05-21 16:37:07.092 sms[5311:207] OK: message-ID XXX110103468XXX
2010-05-21 16:37:07.851 sms[5311:207] Message id: 2
```

I think its returning two because size==2. I need to retrieve the value between the "XXX".

Comment: @shishir Doesn't Ander's solution using `NSScanner` work?

Comment: ITS NOT giving the proper output,i posted my console's output,u can review it.
regards
shishir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS IS WHAT I FINALLY DONE WITH

```
NSString *newString = [[theXML componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
----------------------------------------

NSString *newStr = [newString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [newString length]-1)];
----------------------------------------
```

And I am done.

Answer (score 7):

I think what you need is NSScanner, this allows you to take out parts of the string.

e.g.

```
int n;
NSScanner * scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:@"Your string 1234"];
[scanner scanInt:&n];
```

Comment: This is the best approach because using `-[NSString intValue]` can be thrown off by locale.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this: you want to match `\d+`, that is, a non-zero sequence of digits.

#### Related questions

- [Best regex library for iphone sdk app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444772/best-regex-library-for-iphone-sdk-app)

---

Otherwise, you can just manually go through the characters in the string and find any contiguous sequence of digits.

Comment: But watch out for users with digits in their usernames... Better look for the "my number is" string first, and start scanning from there.

Answer (score 1):

Self contained solution:

```
+ (NSString *)extractNumberFromText:(NSString *)text
{
  NSCharacterSet *nonDigitCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
  return [[text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonDigitCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

Handles the following cases:

- `@"1234"` → `@"1234"`
- `@"001234"` → `@"001234"`
- `@"leading text get removed 001234"` → `@"001234"`
- `@"001234 trailing text gets removed"` → `@"001234"`
- `@"a0b0c1d2e3f4"` → `@"001234"`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet just remove character at the end or beginning of a string.

ex.: "abc 10 cd" -> 10 (it will work)

ex.: "abc 10 a 1" -> "10 a 1" (it will not work)

Using regex seem a better idea.

[iphone sdk - Remove all characters except for numbers 0-9 from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160403/iphone-sdk-remove-all-characters-except-for-numbers-0-9-from-a-string)

EDIT:

Check not the accepted answer but the one with more than 50 votes

```
NSString * number = @"(555) 555-555 Office";
NSString * strippedNumber = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [number length])];
```